# NuxtJS - Middleware get and set cookies

Tags: vue.js, cookies, nuxt.js

does anyone have experience on redirecting a user based on the cookies? so basically I need to check before someone enters my app if he has access to it otherwise to redirect him somewhere else.

I am trying to apply my logic into a middleware but I am getting an error each time I try to set cookies (after doing a fetch/axios call): `ERROR  Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

for setting the cookies I am using the `cookies-universal-nuxt` [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-universal-nuxt)

```
export default function (context) {


  let payload = {
    cookie1: context.$cookies.get("cookieName1"),
    cookie2: context.$cookies.get("cookieName2"),
  }

  let cookie1= '';
  let cookie2= '';

  context.store.dispatch('checknCookies', payload)      
  .then(() => {
    cookie1= context.store.getters.getCookie1;
    cookie2= context.store.getters.getCookie2;

    context.$cookies.set('cookieName1', cookie1, {
      path: '/',
      maxAge: 10,
      expires: 0,
      // domain: 'localhost'
    })

    context.$cookies.set('cookieName2', cookie2, {
      path: '/',
      maxAge: 10,
      expires: 0,
      // domain: 'localhost'
    })
  })
})
```

When I try to set the cookies before calling the store (where I do an axios call to retrieve the names of the cookies) they are set fine. after the axios call then I get the above error.

I haven't found anything that it can help me and I looked at almost all the questions in here which are similar to this.